# Why .NET can't "serialize" my javascript in this code?

Tags: c#, .net

I send to a webservice this Javascript object :

```
list [Object { id="6605", ordine=1 }, Object { id="6602", ordine=2}]
```

On the webservice, I tried to browse this list :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string UpdateOrdineFoto(MyObjects[] list)
{
    string tmp = "";
    foreach (MyObject obj in list)
    {
        tmp += obj.IDFoto + " - " + obj.OrdineFoto + " - ";
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

but on Client side, when I print the string, it wrote : `0 - 0 - 0 - 0 -`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: maybe because IDFoto and OrdineFoto equals 0 ?

Comment: Damn, wrong variable names :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
tmp += obj.id+ " - " + obj.ordine+ " - ";
```